# Chef conditionally stop service

Tags: chef-infra

I have two recipes.

web::foo
web::bar

bar has a service, we will call buzz

How can you do a conditional dependency in the foo cookbook so that.

- If bar::service[buzz] is running, it gets stopped
- If bar::service[buzz] is not running, then just skip the notify.

Something like this should work

web::foo

```
powershell "do stuff" do
  code "echo derp"
  notifies :stop "service[buzz]" if node.run_list?('recipe[web::bar]')
end
```

However this only stops the buzz service if the recipe is included. It has the side affect that if the buzz service is present, but hasn't started yet, it will fail.

Whats the best way to only stop service if it is defined?

Comment: Also - have you considered using `status_command` to query it? The status_command parameter allows you to specify any arbitrary command you like when calling `service`. You could store that in a variable for your if check or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax.

```
if node['recipes'].include?('bar::buzz')
```

(You must have the cookbook name `bar::` in front of the recipe name `buzz` )

The service that manages buzz needs to be intrinsically idempotent so that if the service isn't running, and it tries to stop it anyway, it will will still exit cleanly.

Thanks to coderanger in IRC for clarifying this.

https://gist.github.com/kwilczynski/c271f251ea7f48ba99b3

Comment: There are risks in using node['recipes'].  Things _may_ have changed, but last I looked that only included recipes in the expanded run_list.  It did _not_ include any recipes that are run due to `include_recipe` statements.   That _may_ be ok in your use case, but I thought I'd point it out.